# mongodb lookup - depend on a field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

is it possible to made a lookup which depends on a field in witch collection the lookup points?

```
_id: ObjectId('605351a69b9c3031e94f1e87')
type: 1
actionId: ObjectId('503351a69b9c3031e94f1e83')
```

The actionID can hold a id from the user collection or a document id from another collection. It depend on the type.

For example:

- with type 1 is the actionId is a id from the users collection.

```
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'actionId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'lookup_users',
        },
      },
```

- with type 2 is the actionId a id from the localities collection.

```
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'localities',
          localField: 'actionId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'lookup_localities',
        },
      },
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Yo cannot perform join on two collections in same `$lookup`. Perform 2 `$lookup`s and merge your result into single array.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat thank you for your answer. I can't make 2 lookups because i habe only 1 id (actionId) and the lookup depends on the type.

Comment: please correct me if im wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

Use two lookup pipelines

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: 'actionId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'lookup_users',
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'localities',
      localField: 'actionId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'lookup_localities',
    },
  }
])
```

Sample output

- `{ _id: 1, lookup_users:[{ _id:'userid1': name: 'john' }], lookup_localities:[] }` // lookup_localities empty array here as id is mapped to users collection here
- `{ _id: 1, lookup_users:[], lookup_localities:[{ _id:'localities1': city: 'abc' }] }` // lookup_users empty array here as id is mapped to localities collection here